# Vaadin - Dynamic layout background

Tags: java, css, vaadin

I’m trying to change the background image of a layout on a button click. I used following css rules to add a background initially and in the button click event I tried to override the css rules.

```
.appname .v-desktop {
     background: url(icons/material_wallpaper.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Overriding code

```
    private void setImage(String url) {
         Styles styles = Page.getCurrent().getStyles();
         styles.add(".appname .v-desktop {"
            +"background: url(icons/img.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;"
            +"-webkit-background-size: cover;"
            +"-moz-background-size: cover;"
            +"-o-background-size: cover;"
            +"background-size: cover;}");
     }
```

It won’t work as expected. When I check the css rules from inspect element feature of the browser, css rules are overridden correctly.
Any help

Answer (score 2):

You should add a style (say "changed-background") on button click:

```
button.addClickListener(...){
   myLayout.addStyleName("changed-background");

}
```

In your theme SCSS file, add a custom style

```
.changed-background{
    background: url(icons/material_wallpaper.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```